# How do I tell active or currently logged users in Laravel 5.3 Application?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Question, is is possible that I can get a list of users currently logged in (on-line) a laravel application? Well, just like in Facebook where they show users that are currently on-line.

Comment: You want to get the list of all users which are online(Logged in) in your application?

Comment: Yes @MayankPandeyz currently online users.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to maintain a column in some table like

> is_logged_in - enum(0,1)

which is 1 when user is logged in and 0 when log out.

And use this column to get the list of all logged-in or active user by putting a condition on this column.

Comment: Kindly give further more information about the same. How do I effect the same.